# JavaScript variable scope in nested classes - constructor in constructor

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

1) I'd like to build a set of related functions that are all encapsulated inside one object called "stuff".  I'd like to be able to run code when this object is created, and for it to have private variables and functions as well as public properties and methods. There will only be one of these objects.

2) Also encapsulated inside of stuff, I'd like to have constructor functions for creating multiple additional objects.  I'd like these objects to have private and public items, and to be able to access the public and private items from stuff.  I would also like code to run when these objects are created.

I think I accomplished all of this, but my question is whether this pattern makes any sense and if there are any hidden dangers, or better ways to do it.  (It seems to work.)  -Thank you.

```
    // encapsulate all of this into an object named stuff
    stuff = new function () {

        // reference to this
        var _this = this;

        // code, private variable, and functions
        var a, b, c;
        function f1() { }

        // public property, method
        this.prop1 = a + f1(b);
        this.meth1 = function (x) { return f1(this.prop1); }

        // public constructor like function
        this.Obj = function() {

            // code, private variable, and functions
            var d, e, f;
            function f2() { return a + d + f1() + _this.prop1 + _this.meth1(); }

            // public properties and methods
            this.prop2 = _this.prop1 + f2(17);
            this.prop3 = f1(this.prop2);
            this.meth2 = function () { return a + f1() + _this.prop1 + this.prop3 };
        }

    };

    // Usage:
    stuff.prop1 = 7;            // accessing stuff
    stuff.meth1(45);

    obj1 = new stuff.Obj();     // creating Obj's
    obj2 = new stuff.Obj();

    obj1.prop2 = obj2.meth2();  // using Obj's
```

Comment: To me this looks like normal practice. I would write code like that.. 
The only problem is that you should remove the "new" operator from the function. just var stuff= function ()

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich: Removing the `new` would make it fail.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. It's basically a variation on the standard revealing module pattern. You don't normally use `new function() { ... }`, though, because it creates an unnecessary prototype and inserts it between `stuff` and `Object.prototype`. Since you don't use that prototype for anything, that's unnecessary. It's also confusing to many with only a mid-level knowledge of JavaScript.

The more standard way is to just use an inline-invoked function without `new`. This also means you don't need your `_this` variable (though you can have it if you like) *(I've flagged various lines that have been changed)*:

```
// encapsulate all of this into an object named stuff
var stuff = (function() {
    var stuff = {};      // <=== Could be called _this if you like, but the
                         // same name within and without is reasonable given
                         // it's a singleton anyway

    // code, private variable, and functions
    var a, b, c;

    function f1() {}

    // public property, method
    stuff.prop1 = a + f1(b);
    stuff.meth1 = function(x) {
        return f1(stuff.prop1);
        // **     ^^^^^
    };

    // public constructor like function
    stuff.Obj = function() {

        // code, private variable, and functions
        var d, e, f;

        function f2() {
            return a + d + f1() + stuff.prop1 + stuff.meth1();
            // **                 ^^^^^         ^^^^^
        }

        // public properties and methods
        this.prop2 = stuff.prop1 + f2(17);
        // **        ^^^^^
        this.prop3 = f1(this.prop2);
        this.meth2 = function() {
            return a + f1() + stuff.prop1 + this.prop3
            // **             ^^^^^
        };
    };

    return stuff; // <===
})();

// Usage:
stuff.prop1 = 7; // accessing stuff
stuff.meth1(45);

obj1 = new stuff.Obj(); // creating Obj's
obj2 = new stuff.Obj();

obj1.prop2 = obj2.meth2(); // using Obj's
```

I also added `var` in front of the outer `stuff` to avoid [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: Thank you T.J Crowder,

So are you saying that the following is a common pattern:

        `var obj = (function () { 
            var out = {}; 
            out.prop = 7; 
            return out; 
        })();`

Also, am I correct that the line in your answer,`this.prop1 = a + f1(b);` should be `stuff.prop1 = a + f1(b);`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @StormDog: Yup, that's a common pattern. And yes, you're right, that line and the one after (fixed above).